# variable in the Layout

Tags: cakephp

I am using CakePHP on my website and I need to parse a variable and write it in the layout. The variable is in the MySQL, table "articles", column "author".

If inside an article I write  it shows me the author,
but if I write it in the views/layout/default.thtml it doesn't show me anything.

Is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: Where have you placed the variable? Could you update your question with the contents of your layout (`default.ctp`). Also any relevant controller code might come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Are you obtaining this variable in the right controller function? Maybe you need to insert it in a beforeRender function (http://planetcakephp.org/aggregator/items/1398-utilizing-the-appcontrollerbeforerender-to-assign-cakephps-controller-attribut)

Answer (score 0):

One option to do this is by using CakePHP's `requestAction` and place it in an element you can tag to the default layout. Basically you would do something similar to the following

```
//Create a function in your articles controller as such
function authorName($articleId = NULL){    
   //Return Author if an ID is passed
    if(!empty($articleId)){
        $this->Article->recursive = -1;
        $article = $this->Article->findById($articleID);

        $return $article['Article']['author'];
    }

}

// Then create an element author_name.ctp and place it in views/elements 
// that requests the AuthorID form the above function
<div>
<?php 
    $author = $this->requestAction(
        array(
            'controller' => 'articles', 
            'action' => 'authorName'
        ), 
        array(
            'pass' => $article_id
        )
    );
    echo $author;
?>
</div>

// Then in you default layout or anywhere else 
// you can include the element as such
// You have to figure out a way to get the $id. If you can place a screenshot
// Or some code of you default layout area where you need this, we can help you further
<?php echo $this->element('author_name', array('article_id' => $id)); ?>
```